# Hashing tokens with django rest

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication

I am creating a REST API with django-rest-framework.  The framework supports token authentication but this feature does not seem to be very robust.  For example, I would like to hash the tokens before they are inserted in the DB as well as add a salt.

Can I hash and salt a token with the authentication mechanism in django-rest?

Thanks

Comment: Question is, why would you want to do that? What do you expect to gain by doing this? You can always define your own authentication scheme that would do this if you are certain this is the way to go.

Comment: I subscribe to previous comment. Also, why would you need to store them in the DB? Consider using JSON Web Token authentication with [`django-rest-framework-jwt`](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt).

Comment: Agreed with the previous comments. If like to add the following from the documentation that specifically calls for this to be a simple solution. Not ideal for all scenarios. "This authentication scheme uses a simple token-based HTTP Authentication scheme. Token authentication is appropriate for client-server setups, such as native desktop and mobile clients."

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt). It's a modern way of authentication and doesn't require any DB operation. Also you can send some data to front end like the roles and other non secure user information.